# SVG icons are cut from website when bundle with parcel@2.0.0-beta.2

Tags: html, svg, sass, parcel

I have a small problem, I'm building a project using html, scss, parcel, for bundling and for scss transformer to css, svg icons. All works good until I finally finish my project and try to build (bundle). In nomal form, without bundling, svg icons looks ok:

[image: Unbundled-icons]

But after I bundle/build and upload on netlify, svg icons look terrible:

[image]

Can anyone help me please!!

Comment: Maybe you have repeated id-s or styles inside the svg elements. Can you give us a link to your project?

Comment: I increse width and height a little bit and its works now, but idk why...

Comment: Looks like there no ``viewBox`` definitions

Comment: it is, 0 0 20 20